# Symfony app/console cache:clear --env=prod and cache (APC, Memcached, etc)?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I'm using a Memcached server (along with memcache PHP extension) to cache validator metadata and Doctrine metatada/result/query cache driver.

Everything works as expected and is *fast* compared to filesystem cache.

My question is, does the command:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

automatically clear all types of cache (including memcache)?

After running this command and checking the server stats, items count is always the same as well as cache occupation:

[image]

My configuration, where %prod_cache% parameter is actually the string `memcache`:

```
# Framework Configuration
framework:
    validation:
        cache: %prod_cache% # Matches validator cache service

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: cache_%prod_cache%
        result_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: cache_%prod_cache%
        query_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: cache_%prod_cache%

# DoctrineCacheBundle Configuration
doctrine_cache:
    providers:
        memcache:
            type: memcache
            alias: cache_memcache

# Services
services:
    validator.mapping.cache.memcache: # Validator cache service
        class: Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Cache\DoctrineCache
        arguments: [@cache_memcache]
```

Answer (score 16):

**cache:clear**

The `cache:clear` command doesn't clear the Doctrine caches. It only clears some Symfony 2 framework specific caches, mainly the `app/cache` (or `var/cache`) directories.

**Doctrine commands**

In order to clear the Doctrine caches, use:

- `doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --env=prod`
- `doctrine:cache:clear-query --env=prod`
- `doctrine:cache:clear-result --env=prod`

**Additional caches**

If you use additional cache stores, you'll have to clear them yourself. You can look at the `doctrine:cache:clear-*` commands to get inspired on how to create your own command.

But looking at you configuration, you use a single cache store for the 3 Doctrine caches and Symfony Validator cache. So calling just one of the `doctrine:cache:clear-*` should clear everything.

**Off topic**

When using a cache system like APC, OPcache, and maybe others, you'll have to understand that when you run a PHP script from the command line, a different memory space is used then when running a PHP script from a webserver.

In other words: when you clear such caches from the command line, the caches used by the webserver are *not* affected. In order to clear the webserver caches, you'll need to run the cache clear script(s) from the webserver itself.

This is not an issue for memcached, because it's a separate program managing its own memory space.

Comment: dont forget to add --env=prod at the end of the doctrine commands!

Answer (score 6):

You have to clear external cache yourself, from the doc (SF 2.5):

> There may be lots of other things that you need to do, depending on
>   your setup:
>           [...] Clearing your APC cache

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html#e-other-things

Comment: Symfony/Doctrine actually has commands for this, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24652434/1237411)

Answer (score 4):

This command do not clears the Memcache since it is a standalone distributed memory cacher.
It clears the Symfony cache only.
To clear the memcache you have to run manually :

```
echo 'flush_all' | nc localhost 11211
```

But I think you know that already.

Answer (score 2):

The clear:cache commands only empty the symfony cache in the filesystem then warmup it.
You can use some additional bundles to clear other caches:

Memcache: https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle

APC: https://github.com/ornicar/ApcBundle

Answer (score 1):

If you check vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php you will see that Symfony clears the cache using the file system service.  It clears the cache by removing the old directory.

Here is the exact function (Symfony 2.4)

```
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $realCacheDir = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.cache_dir');
    $oldCacheDir  = $realCacheDir.'_old';
    $filesystem   = $this->getContainer()->get('filesystem');

    if (!is_writable($realCacheDir)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Unable to write in the "%s" directory', $realCacheDir));
    }

    if ($filesystem->exists($oldCacheDir)) {
        $filesystem->remove($oldCacheDir);
    }

    $kernel = $this->getContainer()->get('kernel');
    $output->writeln(sprintf('Clearing the cache for the <info>%s</info> environment with debug <info>%s</info>', $kernel->getEnvironment(), var_export($kernel->isDebug(), true)));
    $this->getContainer()->get('cache_clearer')->clear($realCacheDir);

    if ($input->getOption('no-warmup')) {
        $filesystem->rename($realCacheDir, $oldCacheDir);
    } else {
        // the warmup cache dir name must have the same length than the real one
        // to avoid the many problems in serialized resources files
        $warmupDir = substr($realCacheDir, 0, -1).'_';

        if ($filesystem->exists($warmupDir)) {
            $filesystem->remove($warmupDir);
        }

        $this->warmup($warmupDir, $realCacheDir, !$input->getOption('no-optional-warmers'));

        $filesystem->rename($realCacheDir, $oldCacheDir);
        if (defined('PHP_WINDOWS_VERSION_BUILD')) {
            sleep(1);  // workaround for Windows PHP rename bug
        }
        $filesystem->rename($warmupDir, $realCacheDir);
    }

    $filesystem->remove($oldCacheDir);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a cache like APC that uses different memory space for console and web server, you have no other why then to have and interface where you manually clear the cache.

For memcache, memcached, etc. you can hook into the cache:clear command by creating a listener over the kernel.cache_clearer event that runs both the doctrine cache clear commands.

Whatever method you use for clearing the cache, some cache types like **memcache, will not release the memory used**. Instead they will unset the key the next time a get command is issued on that key, or when the memory is full and some keys need to be evicted.

```
class CacheClearDoctrineListener implements CacheClearerInterface
{
/**
 * @var ContainerInterface
 */
protected $container;

protected $environment;

public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
{
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->environment = $container->get('kernel')->getEnvironment();
}

public function clear($cacheDir)
{
    $this->clearCacheMetadata();
    $this->clearCacheQuery();
}

protected function clearCacheMetadata()
{
    // clear cache metadata
    $application = new Application($this->container->get('kernel'));
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $output = new ConsoleOutput();
    $arguments = array(
        "command" => "doctrine:cache:clear-metadata",
        "--env" => $this->environment
    );
    $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
    $returnCode = $application->run($input, $output);

    if ($returnCode != 0) {
        $output->writeln(json_decode(rtrim($output)));
    }
}

protected function clearCacheQuery()
{
    // clear cache query
    $application = new Application($this->container->get('kernel'));
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $output = new ConsoleOutput();
    $arguments = array(
        "command" => "doctrine:cache:clear-query",
        "--env" => $this->environment
    );
    $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
    $returnCode = $application->run($input, $output);

    if ($returnCode != 0) {
        $output->writeln(json_decode(rtrim($output)));
    }
}
}
```

Declare your service something like this:

```
<service id="cache_clear_doctrine_clearer" class="%namespace_of_your_listener%">
    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
    </call>
    <tag name="kernel.cache_clearer"  priority="254" />
</service>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
php app/console memcached:clear --clearAll default
```